# degrees of freedom when obtaining confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, degrees-of-freedom

I am currently getting confused by the idea of degrees of freedom when obtaining confidence intervals after reading section 15 titled "Probability Distribution of Parameters in the Normal Case" in numerical recipes.

The problem I have is simple: I have 20 data points, each with some known error, and I have some theoretical prediction (independent from the any of the measurements).  I would like to find the best fit amplitude to the data points i.e A* (theory line).

To get the reduced chi-squared, I think the degrees of freedom $\nu$ I should be using is 19.  However, in the aforementioned chapter it states:  "As a first example, let us consider the case $\nu = 1$, where we want to find the confidence interval of a single parameter, say a1.",  where we can replace a1 with A.  Are these two "degrees of freedom" completely different things?  And does this also mean that chi2 (1sigma)=minimum_chi2+1 no matter how many data points you have, as long as you are only fitting one parameter?

Comment: How are you "finding the best fit amplitude" without using a degree of freedom? Aren't you estimating it from data?

Comment: I am taking the best fit amplitude as the A which gives me the minimum chi2

Comment: That estimation by best fit in effect imposes a constraint that costs a degree of freedom.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, I am estimating one parameter losing one degree of freedom. I've edited the main text.